# Quine outputs itself in binary

Tags: code-golf, quine, binary

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program that outputs its own source code in the binary **UTF-8** representation.

## Rules

- The source must be at least 1 byte long.
- Your program must *not* take input (or have an unused, empty input).
- The output may be in any convient format.
- Optional trailing newline is allowed.
- Notice that one byte is 8 bits, and the length of the binary UTF-8 representation is necessarily a multiple of 8.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.

## Example

Let's say your source code is `Aä$$€h`, its corresponding UTF-8 binary representation is `010000011100001110100100001001000010010011100010100000101010110001101000`.

If I run `Aä$$€h` the output must be `010000011100001110100100001001000010010011100010100000101010110001101000`.

```
A      --> 01000001
ä      --> 1100001110100100
$      --> 00100100
$      --> 00100100
€      --> 111000101000001010101100
h      --> 01101000
Aä$$€h --> 010000011100001110100100001001000010010011100010100000101010110001101000
```

## String to binary UTF-8 converters

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NCsIwEIX3OcWAlUloK9qFlEAEzyEipKYmUKalTVG3nsWlt/AmXiRWBbsQNw/eDx@vOXtbUxbCBIp67@ggofdlmjNHTe93Q2ZUj@v7NYoel5tF1ilEVtYtFOAIxpVkoJV2xB15XswMvUKObxiKr7fmhCKBxVKITSa3DI7WVQYqQ1yLaS61wjnGmkEXq0GbdsDBDy7BNF1hotmnH1/8GXYhPAE)
- [utf8-convert](https://sites.google.com/site/nathanlexwww/tools/utf8-convert)

Comment: By "binary", do you mean a string representation of the binary values, i.e. a string consisting of only 1's and 0's?

Comment: @mdahmoune Now that's already much better. The question remains how to represent something as UTF-8. Notice that Unicode representation is mainly based on the *looks* of a character (only occasionally on semantic meaning). What if no assigned Unicode glyph looks like a character in the source code? Unicode also has many look-alikes (homoglyphs). How does one decide which one to use? E.g. Dyalog APL has an AND function which may be encoded as `01011110` or `0010011100100010` in UTF-8 (they look pretty alike: `^` vs `∧`)

Comment: Better example: `01111100` and `0010001100100010` encode `|` and `∣`.

Comment: @Adám I think it would be fair to output any binary sequence that corresponds to a symbol that will compile/run in a certain implementation of a language.

Comment: How about machine code? (Commodore C64 takes 28 bytes assuming the machine code itself is the "source")

Comment: Does it have to be a program, not a function that takes a pointer to an output buffer?  Like @MartinRosenau, I'm wondering about machine code.  If a whole program is required, I think we could probably still follow the usual code-golf rules of only counting the actual executable bytes as "the source", not any executable file metadata.  (i.e. the contents of a `.text` section for an x86-64 Linux executable that base2-dumps itself to stdout, perhaps using RIP-relative addressing got get its own code bytes. Or not, because if we have to be an executable, we can be position-dependent and shorter.)

Comment: Does the "binary" dump of UTF-8 have to be in any particular character set or encoding?  Can we choose to dump it in a format that packs 8 binary bits per octet (i.e. actual binary UTF-8, a serialization format for Unicode codepoints)?  Or do you require a text representation of base 2 digits, using the ASCII subset of UTF-8?  Or any choice of pre-existing encoding used for text, like EBCDIC or UTF-16?  Basically it annoys me when people use "binary" to mean a serialization format with 1 bit per character, similar to hex. UTF-8 itself *is* a binary format composed of 0s and 1s.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you can dump it in a format that packs 8 binary bits per octet then any standard quine would count as a binary quine.

Comment: @immibis: that's exactly my point.  In computing, the word "binary" is not sufficient to describe what this question is trying to ask for.  It's fairly clear from context what's intended, but I think I could rules-lawyer my way into a standard quine in a UTF-8 source (i.e. not x86 machine code, because that's not always valid UTF-8) with phrases like "the binary UTF-8 representation", because UTF-8 *is* a binary format for serializing Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Oh, that's probably what @MartinRosenau was getting at.  What about languages that aren't textual in the first place, like machine code?  Many instruction sequences don't form valid UTF-8 sequences, where the upper bits signal how many later bytes are part of the same character.  Can we just have a function base-2 dump itself in ASCII/UTF-8?

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 28 (or 16?) Latin 1 bytes (35 UTF-8 bytes)

```
ñéÑ~"qpx!!xxd -b
ÎdW54|D
Íßó
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/92///DscOpw5F@InFweCEheHhkIC1iCsOOZFc1NHxECsONw5/Ds///)

Hexdump (in Latin 1):

```
00000000: f1e9 d17e 2271 7078 2121 7878 6420 2d62  ...~"qpx!!xxd -b
00000010: 0ace 6457 3534 7c44 0acd dff3            ..dW54|D....
```

Output (binary representation of the same code in UTF-8, not Latin 1):

```
110000111011000111000011101010011100001110010001011111100010001001110001011100000111100000100001001000010111100001111000011001000010000000101101011000100000110111000011100011100110010001010111001101010011010001111100010001000000110111000011100011011100001110011111110000111011001100001010
```

Explanation:

```
ñéÑ~"qpx            " Standard quine. Anything after this doesn't affect the
                    " program's 'quine-ness' unless it modifies text in the buffer
        !!xxd -b    " Run xxd in binary mode on the text
Î                   " On every line...
 dW                 "   delete a WORD
   54|              "   Go to the 54'th character on this line
      D             "   And delete everything after the cursor
Í                   " Remove on every line...
  ó                 "   Any whitespace
 ß                  "   Including newlines
```

---

**Or...**

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16 bytes

```
ñéÑ~"qpx!!xxd -b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DGwysPT6xTKiyoUFSsqEhR0E36/x8A)

Output:

```
00000000: 11000011 10110001 11000011 10101001 11000011 10010001  ......
00000006: 01111110 00100010 01110001 01110000 01111000 00100001  ~"qpx!
0000000c: 00100001 01111000 01111000 01100100 00100000 00101101  !xxd -
00000012: 01100010 00001010                                      b.
```

OP said:

> The output may be in any convenient format.

This outputs in a much more convenient format for V :P (but I'm not sure if that's stretching the rules)

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 20 bytes

```
{s"_~"+{i2b8Te[}%}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7pYKb5OSbs60yjJIiQ1ula1Nr7u/38A)

Surprised to see CJam winning! <sub>we'll see how long that lasts...</sub>

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 105 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0"D34çýÇbεDg•Xó•18в@ƶà©i7j0ìëR6ôRíć7®-jšTìJ1®<×ì]ð0:J"D34çýÇbεDg•Xó•18в@ƶà©i7j0ìëR6ôRíć7®-jšTìJ1®<×ì]ð0:J
```

05AB1E has no UTF-8 conversion builtins, so I have to do everything [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240184/1682559)..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7D7cnndvqkv6oYVHE4c1A0tDiwiaHY9sOLzi0MtM8y@DwmsOrg8wObwk6vPZIu/mhdbpZRxeGHF7jZXhonc3h6YfXxB7eYGDlRVXD/v8HAA) or [verify that it's a quine](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7Cw@3J53b6pL@qGFRxOHNQNLQ4sImh2PbDi84tDLTPMvg8JrDq4PMDm8JOrz2SLv5oXW6WUcXhhxe42V4aJ3N4emH18Qe3mBg5UVd0/7/BwA).

**Explanation:**

**[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:**

The shortest [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) for 05AB1E is this one: `0"D34çý"D34çý` (**14 bytes**) [provided by *@OliverNi*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210). My answer uses a modified version of that quine by adding at the `...` here: `0"D34çý..."D34çý...`. A short explanation of this quine:

```python
0               # Push a 0 to the stack (can be any digit)
 "D34çý"        # Push the string "D34çý" to the stack
        D       # Duplicate this string
         34ç    # Push 34 converted to an ASCII character to the stack: '"'
            ý   # Join everything on the stack (the 0 and both strings) by '"'
                # (output the result implicitly)
```

**Challenge part:**

Now for the challenge part of the code. As I mentioned at the top, 05AB1E has no UTF-8 conversion builtins, so I have to do these things manually. I've used this source as reference on how to do that: [*Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240184/1682559). Here a short summary of that regarding the conversion of Unicode characters to Unicode†:

1. Convert the unicode characters to their unicode values (i.e. `"dЖ丽"` becomes `[100,1046,20029]`)
2. Convert these unicode values to binary (i.e. `[100,1046,20029]` becomes `["1100100","10000010110","100111000111101"]`)
3. Check in which of the following ranges the characters are:

   1. `0x00000000 - 0x0000007F` (0-127): `0xxxxxxx`
   2. `0x00000080 - 0x000007FF` (128-2047): `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`
   3. `0x00000800 - 0x0000FFFF` (2048-65535): `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`
   4. † `0x00010000 - 0x001FFFFF` (65536-2097151): `11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`

†: Unicode is capped at 21 bits, but UTF-8 is capped at 17 bits. So the range of 4 above would instead be:
`0x00010000 - 0x0010FFFF` (65536-1114111): `10000xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`

The character `d` will be in the first range, so 1 byte in UTF-8; character `Ж` is in the second range, so 2 bytes in UTF-8; and character `丽` is in the third range, so 3 bytes in UTF-8.

The `x` in the pattern behind it are filled with the binary of these characters, from right to left. So the `d` (`1100100`) with pattern `0xxxxxxx` becomes `01100100`; the `Ж` (`10000010110`) with pattern `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` becomes `11010000 10010110`; and the `丽` (`100111000111101`) with pattern `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx` becomes `1110x100 10111000 10111101`, after which the remaining `x` are replaced with `0`: `11100100 10111000 10111101`.

So, that approach I also used in my code. Instead of checking the actual ranges, I just look at the length of the binary and compare it to the amount of `x` in the patterns however, since that saves a few bytes.

```python
Ç               # Convert each character in the string to its unicode value
 b              # Convert each value to binary
  ε             # Map over these binary strings:
   Dg           #  Duplicate the string, and get its length
     •Xó•       #  Push compressed integer 8657
         18в    #  Converted to Base-18 as list: [1,8,12,17]
            @   #  Check for each if the length is >= to this value
                #  (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
   ƶ            #  Multiply each by their 1-based index
    à           #  Pop and get its maximum
     ©          #  Store it in the register (without popping)
   i            #  If it is exactly 1 (first range):
    7j          #   Add leading spaces to the binary to make it of length 7
      0ì        #   And prepend a "0"
   ë            #  Else (any of the other ranges):
    R           #   Reverse the binary
     6ô         #   Split it into parts of size 6
       Rí       #   Reverse it (and each individual part) back
    ć           #   Pop, and push the remainder and the head separated to the stack
     7®-        #   Calculate 7 minus the value from the register
        j       #   Add leading spaces to the head binary to make it of that length
         š      #   Add it at the start of the remainder-list again
    Tì          #   Prepend "10" before each part
      J         #   Join the list together
    1®<×        #   Repeat "1" the value from the register - 1 amount of times
        ì       #   Prepend that at the front
  ]             # Close both the if-else statement and map
   ð0:          # Replace all spaces with "0"
      J         # And join all modified binary strings together
                # (which is output implicitly - with trailing newline)
```

[See this 05AB1E answer of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Xó•18в` is `[1,8,12,17]`.

Comment: ?:: `0x00010000 - 0x001FFFFF (65536-2097151): 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx` this range is incorrect :  UTF-8 codepoints that map to 4 bytes only go up to `4^8 + 4^10 - 1`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto It doesn't change my program, but you're indeed right. I've fixed the explanation. You may want to leave the same comment on [the stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240184/1682559) I copied it from. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

*-15 bytes from @Neil and @Shaggy*

```javascript
f=_=>[...Buffer(`f=`+f)].map(x=>x.toString(2).padStart(8,0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQ30lwC7LTLvWwX/AoYoM2UnFNaePw77v3Dv5xXUvM9ky6hdbELW6YiOhziYQCXpzvBGf6cobbDTeZjlZi2uGFlHkbjYvB@9EjtlVT1TPQqTsIIB0ak/fY/g)

Comment: `padStart(8,0)` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: The spec allows for output to be in any convenient format so you could keep the `map` and ditch the `join` to output an array of bits

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQ30lwC7LTLvWwX/AoYoM2UnFNaePw77v3Dv5xXUvM9ky6hdbELW6YiOhziYQCXpzvBGf6cobbDTeZjlZi2uGFlHkbjYvB@9EjtlVT1TPQqTsIIB0ak/fY/g) with output as an array of bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Neil and @Shaggy!!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 42 bytes

```
$_=q(say unpack'B*',"\$_=q($_);eval");eval
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZQozixUqE0ryAxOVvdSUtdRykGLKoSr2mdWpaYowSh/v//l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8AQAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>339</s> <s>308</s> <s>265</s> <s>227</s> <s>225</s> <s>186</s> 184 bytes

```java
v->{var s="v->{var s=%c%s%1$c;return 0+new java.math.BigInteger(s.format(s,34,s).getBytes()).toString(2);}";return 0+new java.math.BigInteger(s.format(s,34,s).getBytes()).toString(2);}
```

-8 bytes thanks to *@NahuelFouilleul* removing the unnecessary `&255` (and an additional -35 for bringing to my attention that the full program specs of the challenge had been revoked and a function is allowed now as well..)
-41 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rZDPasMwDMbvfQpRFrBZa7qtt9AdetthvQx2KT1orps5c5RiKR6l5NlThwb2ArsI/UOffl@NCZf18WewAZnhHT1dZwCexMUTWge7sQT4kOipAqs@W3@EpMvc7Wc5sKB4Czsg2MCQlq/XhBF4M/9LC1tw8fRgy@ikiwSrR3K/UGdl06B8m62v3rJe5aJic2pjbipevKwXrE3lZHsRx0prI@39C/Wsy37@r9eGcmQ5d18hs0xIaSRtsiHqvrg/oJ7MuLC4xrSdmHOeSCBFxirqQtCTM/1wAw)

**Explanation:**

**[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:**

- `var s` contains the unformatted source code String
- `%s` is used to put this String into itself with `s.format(...)`
- `%c`, `%1$c` and `34` are used to format the double-quotes (`"`)
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together

**Challenge part:**

```java
v->{                         //  Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  var s="...";               //   Unformatted source code String
  return 0+                  //   Return, with a leading "0":
   new java.math.BigInteger( //    A BigInteger of:
     s.format(s,34,s)        //     The actual source code String
      .getBytes())           //     Converted to a list of bytes (UTF-8 by default)
   .toString(2);}            //    And convert this BigInteger to a binary-String
```

Comment: [265 bytes](https://tio.run/##nZA/a8MwFMRn@1MIUYMecUT/DSXCHTp3CYEupYOQFaM0lmrp2SUEf3ZXsttCt5Ll3uM47uB3kINcH@r3yVjUfi@VJttznu3QG9uQjr04U5MBRJ4FlGgU2ZKuN1ZX07B@PH/HfEVpGSr6xypUcXOlop1OEZKKvfMsDhG1CTz@rUQWyrv7MgBvND6dUAcG4FfV0vKTmRuK64d6brT6kzw727AkHN2SZaq8BQDhNfbeEi9GeukcTVP03ztTJvJfPEPi1Upj2RJ/fZMQeWa7U0Ddctcj/4g@spki75jtj0dIfMd8nL4A) using lambda, also because all source is ascii seems unsigned int `c&255` is not needed

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul The original question stated "_You must build a full program._" and "_Your output has to be printed to STDOUT._", hence the verbose border-plate code I have instead of a lambda function returning a String. Good point about not needing `&255` however since we don't use any non-ASCII characters, thanks!

Comment: ok i'm not yet very familar with the usages, but other languages like javascript give a lambda returning a string, also i don't understand why in java we don't count the type and the final semicolon when using lambda where could i find rules?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire [_error: incompatible types: byte cannot be converted to Long_](https://tio.run/##nVBNa8MwDL33V4gwgw2p2dehLHSHnbdeCruMHTTFKekSu0SKRyn57Zm9FnbbYRfpSUhPem@PEZf7@nOmDpnhBVt/WgC0XtzQIDnY5BIghrYG0q85RVOl3rRIgQWlJdiAhzXMcfl4ijgAr4tfqEixurmiqgmDfg5@B/TANhU9iuby7r5kY3dOno7iWBuzPbK43oZR7GFIfzQ6byt1vaozKL37gkyjyUrYShpJsLw1xlRT8f8jRT5Q/Mk@V1nyYfzokuSL8h9f@uSaPg@/vaM5O@YtaT923cWsaf4G)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Relevant meta posts: [Untyped functions in static languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/52210); [Unnamed functions in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/52210); [What are our rules about additional code accompanying function submissions?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/52210); [Are we allowed to use empty input we won't use when no input is asked?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12696/52210); [Byte count for named, recursive lambda expression in C#](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13225/52210).

Comment: `s.format(s,34,s).chars().forEach(c->System.out.printf("%08d",new Long(Long.toString(c,2))));` is one byte shorter than `for(int c:s.format(s,34,s).getBytes())System.out.printf("%08d",new Long(Long.toString(c,2)));`, so I guess the quine should be shorter as well, but I can't get how to make it work (hence the previous failure as well).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! And what was the part that you couldn't work out? Personally I remove the content of the String when making changes. Then ctrl+A and paste it in. Then change the inner `var s=""` to `var s=%c%s%1$c`, and every other `"` to `%1$c` and `%` to `%%`.

Comment: Well, that's where I'm lost. However I tried and [here's a new candidate for 184 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZDPasMwDMbvfQpRFrBZa7qtt9AdetthvQx2KT1orps5c5RiKR6l5NlThwb2ArsI/UOffl@NCZf18WewAZnhHT1dZwCexMUTWge7sQT4kOipAqs@W3@EpMvc7Wc5sKB4Czsg2MCQlq/XhBF4M/9LC1tw8fRgy@ikiwSrR3K/UGdl06B8m62v3rJe5aJic2pjbipevKwXrE3lZHsRx0prI@39C/Wsy37@r9eGcmQ5d18hs0xIaSRtsiHqvrg/oJ7MuLC4xrSdmHOeSCBFxirqQtCTM/1wAw). Tell me if I'm wrong somewhere ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, nice approach! Completely forgot about `BigInteger` being pretty short for converting to binary-Strings. And 2 more bytes by changing the `return'0'+` to `return 0+`. Hmm, why is that leading `0` necessary btw? It confuses me that all inner binary-Strings have this leading `0`, but the very first one not when using `BigInteger.toString(2)`..

Comment: You're fast! The `'0'` stayed for only 20 seconds before being changed to `<space>0` in my comment! :-)

Comment: The leading 0 is there because it's required: "Notice that one byte is 8 bits, and the length of the binary UTF-8 representation is necessarily a multiple of 8."

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I know it's required for the challenge. :) I meant that I don't understand why all the other binary substrings are 8 bits with leading 0s, but the first one is not. Although I guess `BigInteger.toString(2)` convert its bytes to binary-Strings of size 8, joins them all together, and convert it back to a BigInteger (implicitly removing the leading 0), before converting to a String?

Comment: Oh, that? It's because BigInteger takes all the bytes as one mega number where bits happen to be spread over several bytes. Only the first zero(es) are not significant: the other ones are significant, so they are shown. It's not as if BigInteger considered each byte to be a number by itself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 187 bytes

```rust
fn f(o:u8){for c in b"go!g)n;t9(zgns!b!ho!c#%#/huds)(zhg!b_n <27zqshou )#z;19c|#-b_n(:|dmrdzg)1(:|||go!l`ho)(zg)0(:|".iter(){if c^o!=36{print!("{:08b}",c^o);}else{f(0);}}}fn main(){f(1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY7ZCsIwFAV/JWkQEnBpFbSL/opLlyzQJpq0L1m@Pd63YWAOx25uzZlrxKlpt5oFbiwakNKoL4TBgulubagX2uEeS4MHsiMnuY2OUS8F7l8a3c83/3PSbIgR31XNEMkBPG3juNjRC1YBxghr81sa6AQrwRRHtU6WsqA4Gp4GPy7X8LVKr5gWoS3rPhV78KxL0@ymwGkJmBJcXT5KQ8dpBSbnPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 46 bytes

```perl6
<say "<$_>~~.EVAL".ords.fmt("%08b",'')>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9@mOLFSQclGJd6urk7PNczRR0kvvyilWC8tt0RDSdXAIklJR11dEyb535oLrN7AwBAIDMAUiDAAcwwMocIQZAARgmJDmBKokCFUKRKFREMUwNVCINxYQwOIrcjmIznFEKEZboYhnINgwp0OETSEG41iLrJtUIOgXEM0@2H@g9sN10ypP5X0kvNzkzQsNO3s9AoSi4pTdZMSi1M1jDT1kjOKiv8DAA)

The standard quine with `.fmt("%08b",'')` formats the list of ordinal values into length 8 binary and joins with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```python
_="print''.join(bin(256|ord(i))[3:]for i in'_=%r;exec _'%_)";exec _
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P95WqaAoM69EXV0vKz8zTyMJiI1MzWryi1I0MjU1o42tYtPyixQyFTLz1ONtVYusUytSkxXi1VXjNZWg7P//AQ)

A modification of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/51011#51011)

-1 bytes by removing the space after 'in' (thanks @mdahmoune)

Comment: -1 byte: u can drop the space after `in`

Comment: you haven't updated your TIO link. also, I tried to do `'%08b'%ord(i)` instead of `bin(256|ord(i))[3:]`, but it didn't work for some reason

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>138</s> 114 bytes

```r
x=function(){rev(rawToBits(rev(charToRaw(sprintf("x=%s;x()",gsub("\\s","",paste(deparse(x),collapse="")))))))};x()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCsIwEEbhuwwIfyA3kGw8gnTZzRinGihJmEltoHj2SPHtvsXTMXpYthxbKhnuUPlAeZ/KLTXDqfhmncqdd1jVlNsC6uFi1w5H/mXbAzTPRp7IV7YmeEplNUF3PpZ15WoSiNy/7/mN8QM)

Uses R’s ability to deparse functions to their character representation. The `rev`s are needed because `rawToBits` puts the least significant bit first. `as.integer` is needed because otherwise the bits are displayed with a leading zero.

Edited once I realised that any convenient output was allowed. Also was out by one on original byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 62 bytes

```python
exec(a:="print(''.join(f'{i:08b}'for i in b'exec(a:=%r)'%a))")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWqaAoM69EQ11dLys/M08jTb0608rAIqlWPS2/SCFTITNPIUkdpla1SFNdNVFTU0nz/38A)

### How it work :

- `exec(a:="print('exec(a:=%r)'%a)")` is a quine
- `f'{i:08b}'` converts `i` into its 8-digits binary representation
- `b'example_string'` is a binary sting. When we iterate over it, it convert the characters by their unicode value
- `''.join( ... for i in ...)` iterate over a string an concatenate the char after the transformation

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 221 bytes

```cs
var s="var s={0}{1}{0};Write(string.Concat(string.Format(s,(char)34,s).Select(z=>Convert.ToString(z,2).PadLeft(8,'0'))));";Write(string.Concat(string.Format(s,(char)34,s).Select(z=>Convert.ToString(z,2).PadLeft(8,'0'))));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodhWCUJVG9RWG9YCSevwosySVI3ikqLMvHQ95/y85MQSGM8tvygXxNPRSM5ILNI0NtEp1tQLTs1JTS7RqLK1AyouSy0q0QvJDwar16jSMdLUC0hM8UlNK9Gw0FE3UNcEAmslOtjx/z8A)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc) with flag `/u:System.String`, 193 bytes

```cs
var s="var s={0}{1}{0};Write(Concat(Format(s,(char)34,s).Select(z=>Convert.ToString(z,2).PadLeft(8,'0'))));";Write(Concat(Format(s,(char)34,s).Select(z=>Convert.ToString(z,2).PadLeft(8,'0'))));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodhWCUJVG9RWG9YCSevwosySVA3n/LzkxBINt/yiXCBVrKORnJFYpGlsolOsqRecmpOaXKJRZWsHVFWWWlSiF5IfXFKUmZeuUaVjpKkXkJjik5pWomGho26grgkE1ko0MfX//3/5BSWZ@XnF//VLrYIri0tSc/UgWgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU tools, 48 bytes

```
trap -- 'trap|xxd -b|cut -b9-64|tr -dc 01' EXIT
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUBBV1dBHcSoqahIUdBNqkkuLQFSlrpmJjUlRQq6KckKBobqCq4RniFc//8DAA)

Comment: thanks, updated indeed it's the shortest variation otherwise should be removed from trap output

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
eval$b=%q[puts "eval$b=%q[#$b]".unpack("B*")]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7UsMUclyVa1MLqgtKRYQQnBV1ZJilXSK80rSEzO1lBy0lLSjP3/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 33 bytes

```
#Q/v(#Q)+]up~-' ;;\[{**b28'0lp}m[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fOVC/TEM5UFM7trSgTlddwdo6JrpaSyvJyELdIKegNjf6/38A)

```
#Q       # Push remaining stack to stack (Quine)
/v       # Drop input (empty string/whatever)
(#Q)+]up # #Q does not add itself. Complete quine, convert to string
~-       # Remove extraneous brackets
' ;;\[   # Remove extraneous spaces
{
 **      # get codepoint
 b2      # Convert to binary
 8'0lp   # Pad to 8 with 0s
}m[      # Apply to each char of quine
```